# How to get the index of a string in google docs using google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I want to search for a string and then replace it with an image on google docs. For that, I want to get the index of the string and then replace it with an image. But I'm unable to get the index of the string so far.

Below is a snippet of what I am doing:

```
var element = '<<19>>';
options = {muteHttpExceptions: true};
var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(mylist[x-1], options);
var image = resp.getBlob();        
//getting the index of element and then replacing it with image
var rangeElement = body.findText(element);
var foundElement = rangeElement.getStartOffset();
body.replaceText(element, body.insertImage(foundElement, image));
```

I've tried using `findText(searchPattern)` but it didn't work as it returns a range element and I'm getting output as `0` everytime.

Comment: I would like to ask you where `<<19>>` is in the Google Document. In order to correctly understand about this, can you provide a sample Document? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: @Tanaike `<<19>>` is a template place holder in the document.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I had asked about the situation that `<<19>>` is put in the Google Document. For example, is there `<<19>>` in a table or list or paragraph? And is `<<19>>` put in a paragraph of only `<<19>>` or put in the middle of paragraph? Because it is required to modify the script for your situation. So I proposed to provide a sample Google Document. But I noticed that an answer has already been posted. I think it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you find text on your document and replace it with an image:

```
function findAndReplaceWithImage() {
  var element = "<<19>>";

  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();

  var image = "your image url";
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(image).getBlob();

  var paragraphs = doc.getParagraphs();
  for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
    var text = paragraphs[i].getText();

    if (text === element) {
      //Found your match
      doc.removeChild(paragraphs[i]);
      doc.insertImage(i, blob);
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!